# MySQL procedure insert into if

Tags: mysql, insert, constraints, procedure

i tried hard to find a solution for my problem. Please forgive if this problem sounds stupid. Also forgive my bad english....
I am new to MySQL.

i have a table called tblRentals(rtlID (PK), rtlCustomerID(FK), rtlCarID(FK), rltPickDate, rtlRetDate, rtlActDate, rtlMilageStart)
where i insert all the rentals.

now i want to insert data with a procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `prcInserRentals`(
CustomerID          int,
CarID           int,
PickupDate          date,
ReturnDate      date,
MilageStart     int
)
BEGIN
insert into tblRentals(rtlCustomerID, rtlCarID, rltPickDate, rtlRetDate, rtlMilageStart)
VALUES (@CustomerID, @CarID, @PickupDate, @ReturnDate, @MilageStart );
END
```

BUT
it should only add a row IF there is no row with rtlCarID AND rtlActDate=Null

BECAUSE if the field "rtlActDate" is NULL than rtlCarID is already rented.

I tried to add a unique constraint to tblRentals with contraint unique (rtlcarID, rtlActDate) but this combination doesnt count NULL as unique. So it only works if rtlActDate is a concrete date.

I hope a made my problem clear. Hope somebody can help!

Comment: `CustomerID` (in parameters) is local variable whereas `@CustomerID` (in query) is user-defined variable. I.e. these are two different and non-related variables. The same about another variables, of course.

Answer (score -1):

Check if data exists before inserting new data

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prcInserRentals( CustomerID int, CarID int, PickupDate date, ReturnDate date, MilageStart int ) 
BEGIN 
    if not exists(Select rtlCarID from tblRentals where rtlCarID = @CarID AND rtlActDate IS Null)
    BEGIN
        insert into tblRentals(rtlCustomerID, rtlCarID, rltPickDate, rtlRetDate, rtlMilageStart) VALUES (@CustomerID, @CarID, @PickupDate, @ReturnDate, @MilageStart ); 
    END
END
```